# Increase chips in Blackjack in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

In an example in class we made a game of BlackJack but the counter does not increase or subtract the chips by plays.
Sorry to put all the code, the class where the problem is STEP 5: CREATE A CHIPS CLASS, thanks for your help.

## STEP 1: IMPORT THE RANDOM MODULE

```
import random

suits = ('Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Spades', 'Clubs')
ranks = ('Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace')
values = {'Two':2, 'Three':3, 'Four':4, 'Five':5, 'Six':6, 'Seven':7, 'Eight':8, 'Nine':9, 'Ten':10, 'Jack':10, 'Queen':10, 'King':10, 'Ace':11}

playing = True
```

## STEP 2: CREATE A CARD CLASS

```
class Card():

    def __init__(self,suit,rank):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank

    def __str__(self):
        return self.rank+ " of "+self.suit
```

## STEP 3: CREATE A DECK CLASS

```
class Deck():

    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = []  # start with an empty list
        for suit in suits:
            for rank in ranks:
                self.deck.append(Card(suit,rank))

    def __str__(self):
        deck_comp = ''
        for card in self.deck:
            deck_comp += '\n'+ card.__str__()
        return "The deck has: "+deck_comp

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.deck)

    def deal(self):
        single_card = self.deck.pop()
        return single_card
```

## STEP 4: CREATE A HAND CLASS

```
class Hand():

    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []  # start with an empty list as we did in the Deck class
        self.value = 0   # start with zero value
        self.aces = 0    # add an attribute to keep track of aces

    def add_card(self,card):
        # card passed in
        # from Deck.deal() --> single Card(suit,rank)
        self.cards.append(card)
        self.value += values[card.rank]

        # track aces
        if card.rank == 'Ace':
            self.aces += 1

    def adjust_for_ace(self):

        # IF TOTAL VALUE > 21 AND I STILL HAVE AN ACE
        # THAN CHANGE MY ACE TO BE A 1 INSTEAD OF AN 11
        while self.value > 21 and self.aces > 0:
            self.value -= 10
            self.aces -= 1
```

## STEP 5: CREATE A CHIPS CLASS

```
class Chips():

    def __init__(self, total=100):
        self.total = total  # This can be set to a default value or supplied by a user input
        self.bet = 0

    def win_bet(self):
        self.total += self.bet

    def lose_bet(self):
        self.total -= self.bet
```

## STEP 6: WRITE A FUNCTION FOR TAKING BETS

```
def take_bet(chips):

    while True:

        try:
            chips.bet = int(input("How many chips would you like to bet?: "))
        except:
            print("Sorry please provide an intenger")
        else:
            if chips.bet > chips.total:
                print(f"Sorry, you do not have enough chips! You have: {chips.total}")
            else:
                break
```

## STEP 7: WRITE A FUNCTION FOR TAKING HITS

```
def hit(deck,hand):

    single_card = deck.deal()
    hand.add_card(single_card)
    hand.adjust_for_ace()
```

## STEP 8: WRITE A FUNCTION PROMPTING THE PLAYER TO HIT OR STAND

```
def hit_or_stand(deck,hand):

    global playing  # to control an upcoming while loop

    while True:
        x = input("Hit or Stand? Enter h or s: ")

        if x[0].lower() == 'h':
            hit(deck,hand)

        elif x[0].lower() == 's':
            print("Player Stands Dealer's Turn")
            playing = False
        else:
            print("Sorry, I did no understand that, Please enter h or s only!")
            continue

        break
```

## STEP 9: WRITE FUNCTIONS TO DISPLAY CARDS

```
def show_some(player,dealer):

    print("DEALERS HAND:")
    print("one card hidden!")
    print(dealer.cards[1])
    print('\n')
    print("PLAYERS HAND:")
    for card in player.cards:
        print(card)

def show_all(player,dealer):

    print("DEALERS HAND:")
    for card in dealer.cards:
        print(card)
    print('\n')
    print("PLAYERS HAND:")
    for card in player.cards:
        print(card)
```

## STEP 10: WRITE FUNCTIONS TO HANDLE END OF GAME SCENARIOS

```
def player_busts(player,dealer,chips):

    print("BUST PLAYER!")
    chips.lose_bet()

def player_wins(player,dealer,chips):
    print("PLAYER WINS!")
    chips.win_bet()

def dealer_busts(player,dealer,chips):
    print("PLAYER WINS! DEALER BUSTED!")
    chips.win_bet()

def dealer_wins(player,dealer,chips):
    print("DEALER WINS!")
    chips.lose_bet()

def push(player,dealer):
    print("Dealer and player tie! PUSH")
```

## AND NOW ON TO THE GAME!!

```
while True:

    # Print an opening statement

    print("WELCOME TO BLACKJACK")
    # Create & shuffle the deck, deal two cards to each player
    deck = Deck()
    deck.shuffle()

    player_hand = Hand()
    player_hand.add_card(deck.deal())
    player_hand.add_card(deck.deal())

    dealer_hand = Hand()
    dealer_hand.add_card(deck.deal())
    dealer_hand.add_card(deck.deal())


    # Set up the Player's chips
    player_chips = Chips()


    # Prompt the Player for their bet
    take_bet(player_chips)


    # Show cards (but keep one dealer card hidden)
    show_some(player_hand,dealer_hand)

    while playing:  # recall this variable from our hit_or_stand function

        # Prompt for Player to Hit or Stand
        hit_or_stand(deck,player_hand)

        # Show cards (but keep one dealer card hidden)
        show_some(player_hand,dealer_hand)

        # If player's hand exceeds 21, run player_busts() and break out of loop
        if player_hand.value > 21:
            player_busts(player_hand,dealer_hand,player_chips)
            break

    # If Player hasn't busted, play Dealer's hand until Dealer reaches 17
    if player_hand.value <=21:

        while dealer_hand.value < 17:
            hit(deck,dealer_hand)

        # Show all cards
        show_all(player_hand,dealer_hand)

        # Run different winning scenarios
        if dealer_hand.value > 21:
            dealer_busts(player_hand,dealer_hand,player_chips)
        elif dealer_hand.value > player_hand.value:
            dealer_wins(player_hand,dealer_hand,player_chips)
        elif dealer_hand.value < player_hand.value:
            player_wins(player_hand,dealer_hand,player_chips)
        else:
            push(player_hand,dealer_hand)

    # Inform Player of their chips total 
    print(f'\n Player total chips are at: {player_chips.total}')

    # Ask to play again
    new_game = input("Would you like to play another hand? y/n ")

    if new_game[0].lower() == 'y':
        playing = True
        continue
    else:
        print("Thank you for playing!")
        break
```

Comment: You might have more luck if you try to isolate the problem. A wall of code is tough to read. Even if someone *can* debug it for you, it's a lot more work to spot the problem without isolating your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You re-initialize `player_chips = Chips()` every hand. Every time you hit this line of code, it resets `player_chips.chips` to 100. This needs to happen outside of your while loop.